# Connect ADB in Wireless mode with PC(Connected with ethernet)

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wireless

I have a google nexus 7 tablet and i am able to test the application in eclipse through usb debugging over USB cable, but i need to debug over wifi which is connected in my nexus 7 tablet and my PC is connected through Ethernet cable.

Both have internet connected with the same router, i.e PC with "ethernet" and tablet with "Wifi"

i have made a try like below

adb tcpip 5555

adb connect 10.0.0.7(this is my device ip address)

but no luck..

How do i achieve the wireless debug application from this scenario..

Helps appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Enable wireless debuging from developers options and get the ip adress of tablet. You may need some custom roms to have this feature.

Go to the adb.exe directory. It should be in sdk/platform-tools

Open the command prompt there.

Write the command

> adb connect 192.168.1.32 (Where your devices ip adress)

Good luck

Comment: I had did many try like your answers before itself for my answer.. but no luck.. i asked from ethernet connected computer to wifi connected android tablet.. but your answer i suited to only wifi connected system to same wifi connected android device.. @Emre